# How to use New-Object of a class present in a C# DLL using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a class in C# say for example

```
public class MyComputer : PSObject
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }
    private string userName;

    public string DeviceName
    {
        get { return deviceName; }
        set { deviceName = value; }
    }
    public string deviceName;
}
```

which is derived from PSObject. 
I am loading the DLL having this code in powershell using import-module.
Then I tried to create a new object of the MyComputer class in PowerShell.

PS C:> $MyCompObj = New-Object MyComputer

but it throws an error saying make sure assembly containing this type is loaded.
Note: I am able to call Cmdlets successfully which is present in the DLL.

I am not sure is this the right way to go ahead on creating a new object.
Please correct to me make this work.

Comment: For completeness, if this still isn't working check to see if you are creating a class within a class. In that case, you will need to use a PLUS sign as the separator instead of a PERIOD. Such as: class A { class B }. To create class B, use "New-Object A+B" instead of "New-Object A.B"

Answer (score 24):

First, make sure the assembly is loaded using

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\path-to\my\assembly.dll")
```

Next, use the fully qualified class name

```
$MyCompObj = New-Object My.Assembly.MyComputer
```

Comment: You can also use Add-Type -path "c:\path-to\my\assembly.dll"

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to have `PSObject` as base. Simply declare class without base.

```
Add-Type -typedef @"
public class MyComputer
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set { _userName = value; }
    }
    string _userName;

    public string DeviceName
    {
        get { return _deviceName; }
        set { _deviceName = value; }
    }
    string _deviceName;
}
"@

New-Object MyComputer | fl *
```

Later when you will work with the object, PowerShell will automatically wrap it into `PsObject` instance.

```
[3]: $a = New-Object MyComputer
[4]: $a -is [psobject]
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
If I am defining the class directly in PowerShell then what you said will work. But the class is inside the C# DLL, so this technique fails.

Comment: C# automatic properties are your friend.  :-)  Just be sure to set the Language parameter to CSharpVersion3.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how it got working.

```
public class MyComputer
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }
    private string userName;

    public string DeviceName
    {
        get { return deviceName; }
        set { deviceName = value; }
    }

    public string deviceName;
}

//PS C:\> $object = New-Object Namespace.ClassName
PS C:\> $object = New-Object Namespace.MyComputer
PS C:\> $object.UserName = "Shaj"
PS C:\> $object.DeviceName = "PowerShell"
```

Comment: This example doesn't work for me. It still get the errors telling me to  verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded. I did verify the assembly is loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is the MyComputer class in a namespace?  If so, you probably need to use the namespace-qualifed name of the class in the New-Object command.

Also, PowerShell does not like the public names DeviceName and deviceName which differ only in case.  You probably meant to declare deviceName private.  (But why not use auto-properties?)

Finally, stej is correct.  There is no need to derive the MyComputer class from PSObject.

Comment: No luck. Tried with namespace too.
Also tried after removing PSObject derivation.

Comment: FYI: MyComputer is a class inside one namespace.