# Get/set file attributes in PowerShell when the path\filename is longer than 260 characters

Tags: .net, powershell, robocopy

I am looking for a way to get and set file attributes (hidden and readonly) in PowerShell for files where the combined path and filename are longer than 260 characters. I know that the .NET classes don't support longer file paths; I've already tried that. Attrib doesn't work either. I get error "Parameter format not correct -". Likewise Dir doesn't work either.

I am using Robocopy to obtain the filenames. Robocopy has no issues with long paths. However, I can't use Robocopy to get/set attributes since I am just using the /L list mode of Robocopy.

Anyone have workarounds for PowerShell?

**Update**:

`subst` does not support extra-long paths. It does seem to work with partial paths though.

`mklink` requires local volumes.

`net use` does not support extra-long paths. It does seem to work with partial paths though.

`New-PSDrive` does not support extra-long paths, not even partial paths.

Comment: The 260 limit is from windows I believe not .NET.

Comment: Have you tried converting the filenames to [8.3 format](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982)?  I have no idea if that would work or be too onerous in your environment nor if it would surmount the issue! Just a thought :)

Comment: Based on [Long Paths in .NET, Part 2 of 3: Long Path Workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/03/26/long-paths-in-net-part-2-of-3-long-path-workarounds-kim-hamilton.aspx) and [SetFileAttributes (kernel32)](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.SetFileAttributes), I think you could write a C# dll and use the information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666337/how-to-use-new-object-of-a-class-present-in-a-c-sharp-dll-using-powershell to use it in PowerShell.

Comment: @nimizen: That seems a little unreliable because I can't guarantee that files and paths won't have similar names. I am working with terabytes and terabytes of files.

Comment: Did you try creating share on the system hosting the long path? That is `net share foo=c:\some\path...` and then `net use \\server\foo`

Comment: It's a linux server, but I don't have access to the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using `subst` command to map the path as a drive letter is worth a shot. It is based on the olden days of DOS and still works on Winndows like so,

```
subst k: c:\some\really\complex\path\with\too\many\subdirs\and\suff\...
```

If `subst` doesn't work, try sharing a directory close to the file and access it via UNC path.

Comment: This might be the last resort if I can't find anything quicker.

Comment: Looking into using partial paths to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Building on vonPryz's answer and your idea to use partial paths, the following works although it's slow and requires error suppression:

```
subst m: 'Insert\a\complete\path\close\to\character\limit'
sleep 1
Push-Location 'm:\rest\of\path\to\the\file' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem | %{
attrib $_
}
subst m: /d
sleep 1
```

This answer also uses SUBST to get close to where we want to be; then, Push-Location sets the long file-names' parent directory as the 'current working directory' [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd).  Push-Location complains about it but it works anyway insofar as Get-ChildItem and ATTRIB appear to work with this 'current working directory' rather than parsing the entire path and as a result, ATTRIB works.